# How to design multilevel ko structures

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have run into problems with knockout.
Basically I have this structure:

```
<div data-bind="visible: Selected">
    <!-- ko with: Selected().element -->
       <div data-bind="foreach: availableItems">
          <!-- ko if: Category() == 'A' -->
                ...do something...
          <!-- /ko --> 
       </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

But this does not work. The view is corrupted when rendering the first "availableItems".
What do I do wrong?

Comment: There is need do look at your viewModel to help you with this problem. So, you could add your viewModel to question or create Fiddle.

Comment: I'm guessing, but it's just a guess since I don't know anything about your viewmodel, nor about what you mean with "does not work". Still, I'm guessing that the `Selected` observable contains a null value initially, making the `Selected().element` fail. If this is the case, you could fix it by changing the `visible: Selected` to a `with: Selected` (after which the inner `with` could be changed to `with: element`).

Comment: The "Selected().element" does not fail. (tested positive without the inner <div> above.)
I wonder if it´s the two <!-- /ko --> messing it up. Can anybody confirm/affirm? If so I could I write the same loops in another fashion?

Comment: The problem is **not** your binding html, that's what we're trying to say. The problem lies either in your viewmodel entirely or when binding to your viewmodel. You can see your binding working in a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/YjYxv/. Please further explain your issue. Do you get an error message (and if so, what does it say?) or do you mean something else with "does not work"? Please make a jsfiddle/jsbin/plunker which shows your issue, since it's impossible to help you with only the above information.

Comment: At the very least, post your viewmodel code, and the error message you're seeing in the debug console. For extra points, tell us what you've tried so far to fix the problem.